# Отсутствие 6g для компиляции веб-приложений на Go

Tags: веб-программирование, golang

Решил попробовать написать веб-приложение на языке Go, но остановился на том, что нужно было откомпилировать файл через

---

```
8g hello.go

8l hello.8.
```

---

(Скорее всего для меня это `6g` и `6l`)

А у меня и помине нету ни `8g`, `8l`, ни `6g`, `6l`, и система вообще о них ничего не знает

Система linux openSUSE leap

Архитектура amd64

Сам Go был установлен через

---

```
sudo zypper install go
```

---

И обычные программы (не веб) компилирует вполне.

Так вот. Мой вопрос стоит конкретно в том, как мне поставить эти нужные программы для компиляции, или же какой обходной путь для этого нужен, чтобы получить исполняемый на сервере файл?

Answer (score 2):

Насчёт того, что у вас 6*, а не 8*, вы правильно подметили, ибо у вас amd64.

Они у вас установлены, да только чтобы их запускать, нужно прописать соответственно

```
go tool 6g
go tool 6l
```

Выведутся инструкции к их применению.

Хотя не знаю, в чём была проблема просто откомпилировать ваш файл, как обычно. Это вполне работает, можете попробовать.